# Javascript to Jscript?

Tags: powerpoint, javascript

I need help with this...

I've found a javascript app online in which I want to insert into powerpoint for a presentation...

Vb support jscript

Can i convert Javascript to Jscript some how? or can someone help me with it....

If wanted just ask for code or site

Comment: The site and/or code would be nice, yea.

Answer (score 1):

JScript is Microsoft's implentation of Javascript. So, the language is compatible. However, this app you found online almost certainly requires that it be run in a browser environment. The environment that Powerpoint runs any scripts in (like JScript) will be very different.

In other words, you can't do it unless there's some way to embed a browser in your Powerpoint presentation.